# Use temporary length \dimen255, temporary count \count255

Tags: tex-core, counters, package-writing, lengths

This Question is mainly important for package writing:

I read in the TeX-Book that `\count255` and `\dimen255` are traditionally used for temporary. Now the number of registers has risen ([see this Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312003/what-are-the-limited-resources-in-latex-tex)). If I keep the `255`s for temporary, can this cause any conflicts with the allocation of TeX? Or are these values kept free (backwards compability)?

Example: TeX allocates the next counter when I use `\newcount\xy`, which is count254. If I use `\newcount\xz`, does `\xz` resolve to count256 or count255? Or does it matter, if I used count255 before?

Long story short: Can I use count255 as a temporary safely even in the newer implementations of TeX? Or should I definitely use my own temps (once declared for every package).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

count255 is still a scratch register (and as insertions still have to be below 255, the block of count/skip/length/box allocations below 255 is still skipped by \new... depending how many `\newinsert` there have been.

Comment: Ok. This means safe to use. But what do you mean by "insertions have to be below 255"?

Comment: @MaestroGlanz if you (or latex.ltx) does  `\newinsert\footins` to allocate a footnote insertion then count, box, length and skip 254 are allocated to `\footins` so `\newcount` would give an error in classic tex if it reached 254, or with newer insertion macros jumps from 253 to 266

Comment: An additional question: The way you stated, how it jumps would suggest, that  count511 (255+256) is also a scratch register for temporaries. Is this true? The reason is, I need two temporaries and this way I wouldnt have to waste resources.

Comment: @MaestroGlanz the registers around 255 are used for internal bookkeeping, don't touch them or everything will break:-) just use \newcount  there are 32000 of them using up a couple won't hurt.